# Change input color box size?

Tags: html, css

How do I change the size of this box? As you can see it is way too big for the given table.

I've tried with padding, borders, width ... etc. Nothing seems to work :/

[This is the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPn0v.png)

```html
<input type='color'>
```

Comment: Post minimum amount of code that can recreate the problem in a snippet

Comment: Please post all relevant code with your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining `border`, `background`, and `padding` properties will get rid of the 'added space'.

The main one that gets rid of the colour is `background`.

```css
input {
  border:0;
  background:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<input type='color'>
```

Updated:

I have found `-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper` and `-webkit-color-swatch`

```css
input{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
input::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
 padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    background:none;
}
input::-webkit-color-swatch {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='color'>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I don't know why people are down voting this so much, when you don't need the code snippet.

Comment: @CholaTech Glad I could help. In fairness it is always best to include the bare minimum of the problem if it is reproducible. Although I understood your original post and edited in the snippet anyway - not sure why others downvoted.

Comment: A quick note, it does hide it, but its still there. I have to reduce its size, just hiding it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: You can also add `padding:0;` to make it smaller @CholaTech

Comment: Doesn't work..
P.s. you already wrote that up there ^.
@Albzi

Comment: Ah yes I did sorry - I miss read what you said! Yes the space around it I can't actually get rid of, I've tried but the best I can do is hide the background colour. @CholaTech

Comment: You can use `margin:-(number)px`. That might help you a bit @CholaTech

Comment: That had the effect of overflowing the table :D
Damn this is annoying. I'll just leave it like that. Still, thank you for the help @Albzi :)

Comment: I found some webkit related styles but don't know how widely supported they are! Check the updated @CholaTech

Comment: AYYYYY finally :D Thanks so much! @Albzi

Comment: Ah glad we got to the bottom of it :D No worries! @CholaTech

Answer (score 0):

You could give your input an ID, and change width and height with css like this.

```
<input type='color' id="myColor">
```

and the css like this,

```
#myColor {
width: 100px;
height: 20px; }
```

Comment: That doesn't work tho. It changes the size of the "color itself", but the box around it stays the same. And that box is what I want to change.

Comment: My bad, misunderstood the question then.

Comment: @user8719783 I think I misunderstood the question too! Thank you for your answer, it's just what I needed xD